# Recycler view click animation

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, material-design, android-cardview, ripple

I'm trying to add some click animation [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJbOw.gif) to my recycler view but unsuccessfully. Here's some of my code.

Inside my Activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    ItemOffsetDecoration itemDecoration = new ItemOffsetDecoration(this, R.dimen.card_item_offset);
    mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(itemDecoration);

    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

Inside my ViewHolder

```
public CustomViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    this.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            /* on click stuff here */
        }
    });
}
```

Inside my CardView.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_loading"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/card_message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Not sure where the problem is, but thank you in advance for helping =)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

this is called Ripple effect you are trying with background instead foreground

```
android:focusable="true"
android:clickable="true"
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

you can also make it custom too

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/colorcode">

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/mask"
        android:drawable="@color/colorcode" />
</ripple>
```

to support in older versions you can do like that

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorcode" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/colorcode" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```